# How to create modal dialog box like when you try to vote on stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for some solution for creating modal dialog box, like when you are not logged in or donot have enought reputation, and try to vote on some question or answer at stack overflow... That orange box that is show...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQueryUI dialogs are a good choice.  I have also used SimpleModal and been very happy with it: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 2):

You could try jQuery [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one: http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html

Answer (score 1):

Those are simple DIV's. No need to load up JQuery just for that.

```
<div class="error_hidden" id="error_dialog">Oops, there was an error!</div>
```

Write the CSS for the "error" and "error_hidden" then use a javascript event to change the class and position of the div, or better yet create a new div dynamically when the event fires.